# How to split 16-bit unsigned integer into array of bytes in python?

Tags: python, arrays, struct, byte

I need to split a 16-bit unsigned integer into an array of bytes (i.e. `array.array('B')`) in python.

For example:

```
>>> reg_val = 0xABCD
[insert python magic here]
>>> print("0x%X" % myarray[0])
0xCD
>>> print("0x%X" % myarray[1])
0xAB
```

The way I'm currently doing it seems very complicated for something so simple:

```
>>> import struct
>>> import array
>>> reg_val = 0xABCD
>>> reg_val_msb, reg_val_lsb = struct.unpack("<BB", struct.pack("<H", (0xFFFF & reg_val)))
>>> myarray = array.array('B')
>>> myarray.append(reg_val_msb)
>>> myarray.append(reg_val_lsb)
```

Is there a better/more efficient/more pythonic way of accomplishing the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(using python 3 here, there are some nomenclature differences in 2)

Well first, you could just leave everything as `bytes`.  This is perfectly valid:

```
reg_val_msb, reg_val_lsb = struct.pack('<H', 0xABCD)
```

`bytes` allows for "tuple unpacking" (not related to `struct.unpack`, tuple unpacking is used all over python).  And `bytes` *is* an array of bytes, which can be accessed via index as you wanted.

```
b = struct.pack('<H',0xABCD)

b[0],b[1]
Out[52]: (205, 171)
```

If you truly wanted to get it into an `array.array('B')`, it's still rather easy:

```
ary = array('B',struct.pack('<H',0xABCD))
# ary = array('B', [205, 171])

print("0x%X" % ary[0])
# 0xCD
```

Comment: can you elaborate on "tuple unpacking" vs. `struct.unpack`?  i.e. is there a difference between `b[0],b[1]` and `struct.unpack('<BB', b)`?

Comment: Not really.  Tuple unpacking is just assigning each element of an iterable length *n* to *n* different variables.  Like `a,b,c = 1,2,3`.

Answer (score 0):

For non-complex numbers you can use [`divmod(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod), which returns a tuple of the quotient and remainder of arguments.

The following example uses `map()` for demonstration purposes. In both examples we're simply telling divmod to return a tuple `(a/b, a%b), where a=0xABCD and b=256`.

```
>>> map(hex, divmod(0xABCD, 1<<8)) # Add a list() call here if your working with python 3.x
['0xab', '0xcd']

# Or if the bit shift notation is distrubing:
>>> map(hex, divmod(0xABCD, 256))
```

Or you can just place them in the array:

```
>>> arr = array.array('B')
>>> arr.extend(divmod(0xABCD, 256))
>>> arr
array('B', [171, 205])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I chose the answer from @roippi because it's more generally applicable (for example can be extended to split 24-bit integers into bytes)

Comment: That's fine but I would like to mention that the `divmod()` can be extended to any bit range by passing a correct parameter to it. For 24 bits: `divmod(0xABCD,0xFFFFFF)`.

Comment: how would you split 0x123456 into bytes 0x12, 0x34, 0x56 using divmod?

Comment: @cdwilson sorry I misunderstood your original comment. Of course this doesn't work with divmod without doing two calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function like this.

```
def binarray(i):
    while i:
        yield i & 0xff
        i = i >> 8

print list(binarray(0xABCD))
#[205, 171]
```