# Pythonic way to convert an integer into a hex-escaped string

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic way to convert an integer into a hex-escaped string?

> 0 -> '\x00'
>
> 15 -> '\x0f'
>
> 0xdeadbeef -> '\xde\xad\xbe\xef'

Comment: @Lix: This is definitely NOT a duplicate of that question, which asks specifically about values <256, which has a trivial solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do what you want directly, but it's not that hard to do yourself.

For example, you can convert the whole int to hex, then insert a `\x` character before every pair of characters:

```
n = 0xdeadbeef
x = format(n, 'x')
s = re.sub('(..)', r'\\x\1', x)
# or s = ''.join(r'\x{}{}'.format(*b) for b in pairwise(x))
# or s = ''.join(r'\x' + x[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(x), 2))
```

Or you could pull off a byte at a time and format them yourself:

```
x = []
while n:
    x.append(n % 256)
    n //= 256
s = ''.join(r'\x{:02x}'.format(b) for b in reversed(x))
```

Which of those is most Pythonic? I think they're all simple enough that if you wrapped them up in a function with an appropriate name, nobody would complain, but all complicated enough that if you just inlined them into your code, it wouldn't be very pythonic. (I'd personally use the `pairwise` version, just because I always think of `itertools` first, but that's just me.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit ambiguous whether you want the 1-byte string `'\x0f'` or the 6-byte string `"'\\x0f'"` (ie. a string which looks like `'\x0f'` when printed). In case you meant the former, here's one way to do that:

```
s = '%x' % 0xdeadbeef
binascii.unhexlify('0' + s if len(s) % 2 else s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how 'pythonic' that is, but here's a solution using a recursive function:

```
def uint_tuple_to_bytes(t):
        if t[0] < 0x100:
                return t
        else:
                return uint_tuple_to_bytes(divmod(t[0], 0x100) + t[1:])

def uint_to_bytes(i):
        return uint_tuple_to_bytes((i,))

def uint_to_binary_string(i):
        return ''.join(chr(byte) for byte in uint_to_bytes(i))
```

(Inspired by the second part ("pull off a byte at a time") of [abarnert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30285968/674064) and by [msvalkon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23352138/674064) to ['How to split 16-bit unsigned integer into array of bytes in python?'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23352097/674064).)